# Assigning a string variable that contains special characters to a string property looses special characters

Tags: c#, string, symbols

I have a statement like below :

```
string city = HandleTypeString(address.City, tokenParams);
address.City =  city; //"_rv!9yfEEZy";
```

The `handleTypeString` returns a string `(_rv!9yfEEZy)` with random special characters. When I save the value in `city` variable, it contains everything that `handleTypeString` returns, but when I assign it to `address.city` it becomes `rv9yfEEZy` losing special characters. I need to store the exact value in the property. How can I preserves the original value on assignment?

Edit: 
I found the issue that the property setter is removing those special characters. 
public string City { get { return this._City; } set { this._City = value.RemoveDiacritics().RemoveSpecialCharacters(); } }

My code failed randomly as the encrypted value didn't contain special characters every time. Thank you all for suggesting to check property definition.

Comment: Can you show what `address.City` does and how it is defined in the class?

Comment: The class is defined in an assembly that my project references. it looks like below:
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "City")]
    [XmlElement("City", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string City
    {
      get
      {
        return this._City;
      }
      set
      {
        this._City = value.RemoveDiacritics().RemoveSpecialCharacters();
      }
    }

Comment: Pretty sure the problem is `value.RemoveDiacritics().RemoveSpecialCharacters(); ` in the setter...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can't change how city property is defined. Unfortunately, I still needs the original value to be stored as it is because the value is sort of encrypted value of the original readable format. I need that to convert back from encrypted to original value.

Comment: The 'RemoveDiacritics().RemoveSpecialCharacters()' in the property setter should be screaming at you.

Comment: If you want to use it "as-is", you'll need to convert it to something that can be stored there, like Base-32, and then convert it back when you read it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`address.City` either modifies the provided value in the setter or in the getter. For example:

```
private string city;
public string City
{
    get { return city; }
    set { city = RemoveSpecialCharacters(value); }
}
```

or

```
private string city;
public string City
{
    get { return RemoveSpecialCharacters(city); }
    set { city = value; }
}
```